# SQL Pivot Table with MAX

Tags: sql, pivot, max

I am stuck with this. I developed an SQL script tu obtain these information:-

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TJQs.jpg)

Here are the codes:-

```
SELECT [COST UNIT],[GL ACCOUNT]+ ' ' + [GL], SUM([CLOSING BALANCE]) AS [TOTAL GL CLOSING BALANCE] FROM 
(
    SELECT AB.StartDate AS [DATE], AB.FreeTextField_04 AS [COST UNIT], IT.GLAccountDistribution AS [GL ACCOUNT], GL.Description AS [GL], ST.ItemCode AS [ITEM CODE] , 
    ST.Description AS [DESCRIPTION],
    IT.UserField_03 AS PACKAGING, ST.StockOnHandUOM AS [U/MEA.], IT.CostPriceStandard AS [STD COST PRICE], ST.PhyStkTakeQty AS [STOCK QTY], 
    CAST(ROUND((ST.PhyStkTakeQty * IT.CostPriceStandard ),2) AS DECIMAL(12,2)) AS [CLOSING BALANCE]
    FROM [001].DBO.CS738281StkTake ST INNER JOIN [001].DBO.Absences AB ON ST.ReqID = AB.ID 
    INNER JOIN [200].DBO.Items IT ON ST.ItemCode = IT.ItemCode
    INNER JOIN [200].DBO.GRV_GLAccounts GL ON IT.GLAccountDistribution = GL.GLAccount
    WHERE AB.StartDate = '2017-08-31 0:00:00.000'
    --AND AB.FreeTextField_02 in ( '1CTY','bsp')
    AND IT.GLAccountDistribution IN (12010010,12010020,12010030,12010040,12010041,12010042,12010043,12010050,12010060,12010080,12030010)
    --ORDER BY [GL ACCOUNT],[ITEM CODE]
) tmp
GROUP BY [GL ACCOUNT], [GL], [COST UNIT]
ORDER BY [COST UNIT],[GL ACCOUNT]
```

My objective is to do pivot table to look like this:-
[Required Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmSue.jpg)

I tried many times but couldn't work. Can anyone help? Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `PIVOT` table operator with `MAX` like this:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT [COST UNIT],[GL ACCOUNT]+ ' ' + [GL], SUM([CLOSING BALANCE]) AS [TOTAL GL CLOSING BALANCE] FROM 
    (


         SELECT AB.StartDate AS [DATE], AB.FreeTextField_04 AS [COST UNIT], IT.GLAccountDistribution AS [GL ACCOUNT], GL.Description AS [GL], ST.ItemCode AS [ITEM CODE] , 
            ST.Description AS [DESCRIPTION],
            IT.UserField_03 AS PACKAGING, ST.StockOnHandUOM AS [U/MEA.], IT.CostPriceStandard AS [STD COST PRICE], ST.PhyStkTakeQty AS [STOCK QTY], 
            CAST(ROUND((ST.PhyStkTakeQty * IT.CostPriceStandard ),2) AS DECIMAL(12,2)) AS [CLOSING BALANCE]
            FROM [001].DBO.CS738281StkTake ST INNER JOIN [001].DBO.Absences AB ON ST.ReqID = AB.ID 
            INNER JOIN [200].DBO.Items IT ON ST.ItemCode = IT.ItemCode
            INNER JOIN [200].DBO.GRV_GLAccounts GL ON IT.GLAccountDistribution = GL.GLAccount
            WHERE AB.StartDate = '2017-08-31 0:00:00.000'
            --AND AB.FreeTextField_02 in ( '1CTY','bsp')
            AND IT.GLAccountDistribution IN (12010010,12010020,12010030,12010040,12010041,12010042,12010043,12010050,12010060,12010080,12030010)
            --ORDER BY [GL ACCOUNT],[ITEM CODE]

    ) tmp
    GROUP BY [GL ACCOUNT], [GL], [COST UNIT]
)
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT GL, [COST UNIT], [TOTAL GL CLOSING BALANCE]
    FROM CTE 
) AS t
PIVOT
(
  MAX([TOTAL GL CLOSING BALANCE])
  FOR [COST UNIT] IN([1CTY], [AMCP], [AMPO])
) AS p
```

Comment: Hi Dimitri, thank you for your feedback. I have tried your script and it returns an error:-

    Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
    No column name was specified for column 2 of 'MyCTE'.